What are the lyrics to the song "Let It Rain"?
I can’t find the lyrics online to the song named "Let it Rain", sung by Henrik Lairs Wikstrom, Niklas Rolf Edberger and Anders Gunnar Kampe. It's included in the album "Uplifting Pop". I am not a native English speaker, and without the lyrics, it is difficult for me to understand the meaning of the song.

Hi! Identification questions are off-topic here on Music SE.

That's a tough one.  I couldn't find anything either.  I'm assuming this is the correct song: .  I had a listen, nice song.  This is my best guess, I think it's right on:
And I fell down and I am out
Can hardly speak, but I wanna shout
When all are smilin' but I can't join in
Sun is shinin' but my heart is cloudy
Then just, let it rain
Let the sun take a break
Let it wash my worries away
Oh oh ho, let it rain
Let it drain all the thoughts from my past
There's nothing to say
So let it rain, to make me feel again
Rain, to make me feel again
Till I'm OK, so let it, let it rain
Don't have to face the world alone
Gonna find my way back home
It'll be a better day tomorrow
Rain or sun, I know my heart is shining
Then just, let it rain
Let the sun take a break
Let it wash my worries away
Oh oh ho, let it rain
Let it drain all the thoughts from my past
There's nothing to say
So let it rain, to make me feel again
Rain, to make me feel again
Till I'm OK, so let it, let it rain
Let it rain
Till I'm OK, I'm OK [some nonverbal sound]
So let it rain, to make me feel again
Rain, to make me feel again
Till I'm OK, so let it, let it rain
I'm OK, I'm OK
Rock on,
citizen127
